# Resizing Table View Cells to Display UITextView and a UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I need to dynamically set the height of any cell that contains a UILabel and a UITextView like so:

[image: xcode project from Tyler Fox/smileyborg]

But I also need it for a web view to display text converted into Markdown:

[image: my project]

But i would need this web view to be in a table view cell. In other words, the web view would act the same as the UITextView in the first screenshot

Other conditions are:

- The subject line can be blank therefore the UILabel would not be there
- The web view will have its content scaled smaller to allow the cells to not be too large
- there is a cell height limit defined by the user; 196 as an example

Comment: What is your question?  What part of what you are trying to do are you not able to accomplish?  What have you already tried?

Comment: I've been able to use PureLayout but I was hoping to have it layout a web view

Comment: https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout

Answer (score 1):

The difficult problem when trying to resize a web view to fit it's content is the fact that the web view itself does not have any idea how tall the content of the DOM being displayed inside of it might be.  What you have to do is ask the DOM how tall it is and adjust your table view cell and the web view it contains, to match the height of the DOM.  To do this you can ask the DOM how tall it is through JavaScript.  In our code we do it something like this:

```
[detailsWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.height"]
```

This asks the DOM to tell you how tall its HTML content is.  With that information in mind you can figure out how tall your web view needs to be and this should help you figure out how tall your table cell must be.